# Android-finish function in activity didn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I extend activity A, B, C from MainActivity.
A start in first and A start B and B start C.
when I use finish() in onclick special Button in activity C, Activity A is start, but I want activity B start.
What I do for this case?

Comment: check intent filters you are using and check noHistory xml attribute in AndroidManifest associated with activities

Comment: @Shubham I didn't use noHistory, I check it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start all activity like below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);

startActivity(i);
```

don't add *finish()* method, then inside button click just call *finish()* method. It will bring you back to previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably expect Activity B to be on the stack when Activity C finishes since Android can destroy a background Activity if it needs memory. If your use case suggests that Activity B should always become visible when Activity C is closed, you should start it explicitly, as described in [Navigating Up to Parent Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp). In your case, I think it's appropriate to use `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` in `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: in this code B may start from A and other activity and did't have fixed parent

Comment: You have to specify parent for C, not for B.

Comment: I forgot to say that C activity start D activity and, in C and D when I use finish function ,A activity start

Comment: The idea is that you shouldn't expect any previous Activity to remain in the task when the next one finishes. Design your application with this idea in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> AActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,BActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

> BActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,CActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

> CActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,BActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```